# Why does gradle not run in the Terminal Window in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When I open the **Terminal** window (**View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal**) in IntelliJ IDEA, and type `gradle tasks`, this is what I get to see:

```
C:\Sathyaish\MyJavaAndSpringBootProject>gradle tasks
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I presume from the fact that IntelliJ IDEA shows the **Gradle** tool window (**View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle**) and the fact that the IDE is able to run gradle tasks, and list gradle dependencies, that the IDE automatically also installed gradle on my machine.

I searched my machine for a **gradle** folder that also had a **bin** directory but couldn't find any. I know that *I* haven't installed gradle on my own.

I did find a **gradle** folder inside the IntelliJ IDEA installation folder here:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\gradle>dir /b
lib

C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\gradle>dir lib /b
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
gradle-base-services-3.5.jar
gradle-base-services-groovy-3.5.jar
gradle-cli-3.5.jar
gradle-core-3.5.jar
gradle-jps-plugin.jar
gradle-logging-3.5.jar
gradle-messaging-3.5.jar
gradle-model-core-3.5.jar
gradle-model-groovy-3.5.jar
gradle-native-3.5.jar
gradle-process-services-3.5.jar
gradle-resources-3.5.jar
gradle-tooling-api-3.5.jar
gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar
gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar
gradle-version-info-3.5.jar
gradle-wrapper-3.5.jar
gradle.jar
guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
jansi-1.14.jar
kryo-2.22.jar
minlog-1.2.jar
native-platform-0.14.jar
native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libcpp-0.14.jar
native-platform-freebsd-amd64-libstdcpp-0.14.jar
native-platform-freebsd-i386-libcpp-0.14.jar
native-platform-freebsd-i386-libstdcpp-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses5-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-amd64-ncurses6-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses5-0.14.jar
native-platform-linux-i386-ncurses6-0.14.jar
native-platform-osx-amd64-0.14.jar
native-platform-osx-i386-0.14.jar
native-platform-windows-amd64-0.14.jar
native-platform-windows-i386-0.14.jar
objenesis-1.2.jar
reflectasm-1.07.jar
resources_en.jar

C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\gradle>
```

How may I run the command `gradle tasks` to list all gradle tasks from within the IntelliJ IDEA **Terminal** window? Should I add **C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1\plugins\gradle\lib** to the **PATH** environment variable on my machine?

Comment: If you want to use gradle, you have to install gradle.

Comment: The good practice is to use the gradle wrapper. Look for that term in the documentation, and check if you have a `gradlew` file in your project.

Comment: Yes, IntelliJ installed the **gradle-wrapper** and I do see the file you mention and also files named **gradle-wrapper.jar** and **gradle-wrapper.properties** in a separate folder named **gradle** inside the project root.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm reading through the documentation. It's a lot to take in. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA uses the *Gradle Wrapper* or the *Gradle distributed location* that you specify in your IntelliJ IDEA settings, but when you are using the terminal window, it uses your native operating system command line, so if you don't have Gradle configured in your `PATH` environment variable, it will just not work because it doesn't know what `gradle` is.

Add `gradle` to your path in:

**Windows**

In File Explorer right-click on the This PC (or Computer) icon, then click Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables.

Under System Variables select Path, then click Edit.
Add an entry for C:\Gradle\gradle-3.5\bin. Click OK to save.

**Linux / Mac**

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-3.5/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add the directory containing `gradle.bat` to `PATH` and restart IntelliJ IDEA.

The full path can look like this: `d:\dev\gradle-3.5\bin`.

Answer (score -1):

If you start an IntelliJ project with gradle, it puts a standalone gradle wrapper (`gradlew`) in your project's root directory. You can access it from the terminal by typing `gradlew` instead of `gradle`.